# Perl - How to push an element into a particular position in a multidimensional array in Perl?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, push, element

How do I push an element into a particular position in a multidimensional array in Perl? Currently I am using the '=' sign to assign an element "apple" into the array but I think it's wrong.

```
my @matrix;
$matX = 0;
$matY = 0;
$matrix[0][0] = $h;
$matrix[$matX][$matY] = "apple";
```

I want the  $matrix[$matX][$matY] to contain the element "apple" and $matrix[0][0] to contain the variable $h.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried your code? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown the output, so from the code i'm guessing that $matrix[0][0] gets overwritten as your $matX=0 and $maxY=0.
This code:

```
my @matrix;
$matX = 1;
$matY = 1;
$h = "variable h";
$matrix[0][0] = $h;
$matrix[$matX][$matY] = "apple";
print $matrix[0][0] . "\n";
print $matrix[$matX][$matY] . "\n";
```

(note that $matX and $matY are now '1')

produces

```
variable h
apple
```

Comment: I thought we need to use 'push' in perl to add elements into a multidimensional array. Thanks rbm that helps.